# ORDER BY column from the joined table performance

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How can I improve this? It takes around half a second and it's just a demo query. 
The problem here is the ORDER BY, but I can't really do without it. I also need empty rows of the LEFT JOIN for missing records in `something` table.

```
SELECT c.name 
FROM customers c 
LEFT JOIN something s USING(customer_id) 
ORDER BY s.test DESC LIMIT 25
```

---

DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
 customer_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),
 KEY namne (name(999))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=100001 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin

CREATE TABLE something (
 id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 customer_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 text longtext NOT NULL,
 test varchar(5) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 KEY customer_id (customer_id),
 KEY text (text(999)),
 KEY test (test),
 KEY asdasd (customer_id,test)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys      | key    | key_len | ref                | rows   | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL  | NULL               | NULL   | NULL    | NULL               | 100000 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | s     | ref  | customer_id,asdasd | asdasd | 4       | test.c.customer_id |      2 | Using index                     |
+------+-------------+-------+------+--------------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: try adding index on the table

Comment: @srp, could you be more specific?..

Comment: To improve query performance , indexes are to be added. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm

Comment: Why are you using a ***LEFT** JOIN*? It doesn't seem reasonable to order by a column from the left joined table.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the LEFT JOIN makes sence here. If you replace it by an INNER JOIN, the engine would be able to use the `KEY test (test)` for the ORDER BY clause. So all you need might be this:

```
SELECT c.name 
FROM customers c 
INNER JOIN something s USING(customer_id) 
ORDER BY s.test DESC LIMIT 25
```

But to get the exactly same result as with the LEFT JOIN you can combine two fast queries with `UNION ALL`:

```
(
    SELECT c.name 
    FROM customers c 
    LEFT JOIN something s USING(customer_id) 
    ORDER BY s.test DESC LIMIT 25
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT c.name 
    FROM customers c 
    LEFT JOIN something s USING(customer_id)
    WHERE s.customer_id IS NULL
    LIMIT 25
)
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: Well maybe my query was too simplified, this might resemble the original query better: 
`SELECT c.name, IF(s.id, 1, 0) as thing
FROM customers c 
LEFT JOIN something s USING(customer_id) 
ORDER BY thing DESC LIMIT 25`. I don't think Inner join would be a good fit as I also need not matching rows to check `thing` and then sort by it. (if you're wondering the use case for this - just think of table grid made up of data from several tables, columns are sortable).

Comment: @bah That is a different question. But since you only want id=0 to be ordered last, you could as good use `ORDER BY s.id DESC` and my answer would be applicable to it.

Answer (score 0):

- Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.
- Use some sensible limit in a `VARCHAR(..)` instead of `TEXT`.
- Then get rid of "prefix indexing" if possible.
- `INDEX(a)` is redundant when you have `INDEX(a,b)`.

For more speed:

```
SELECT  name
    FROM  ( 
            (  SELECT  c.name, s.test
                    FROM  customers c
                    JOIN  something s USING(customer_id)
                    ORDER BY  s.test DESC
                    LIMIT  25
            )
        UNION ALL
            (  SELECT  c.name, NULL
                    FROM  customers c
                    LEFT JOIN  something s USING(customer_id)
                    WHERE  s.test IS NULL
                    LIMIT  25
            ) 
        ) AS x
    ORDER BY  test DESC
    LIMIT  25
```

And have

```
INDEX(test, customer_id)
```